# PHP cURL not returning all results

Tags: php, json, curl, skyscanner

I have a very strange problem. I am trying to return an array from a JSON GET request using the Skyscanner API.

The Skyscanner URL I am generating and using in the cURL is: http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/browseroutes/v1.0/DE/EUR/de-DE/HAM/PT/2016-12?apiKey=API_KEY

It returns 3 quotes but when I am using a JSON editor like http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ it gives me 9 quotes!!!

Why does it show less quotes in my solution? And how do I get all quotes???

```php
<?php

$cities = array("HAM");
$countries = array("PT");
$url_api = "http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/browseroutes/v1.0/DE/EUR/de-DE/";
$api_key = "API_KEY_HERE";

$next_month = date('m')+1;
if ($next_month=="13") {
    $this_year = date('Y')+1;
    $next_month = "01";
} else {
    $this_year = date('Y');
}

foreach($cities as $city){

    foreach($countries as $country){
    $url = $url_api.$city."/".$country."/".$this_year."-".$next_month."?apiKey=".$api_key;
    $ip = "218.255.245.210";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'X_FORWARDED_FOR: '.$ip));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = json_decode($data);
    echo $url."<br/>";
    $quotes = $response->Quotes;
    foreach($quotes as $quote){
        echo $quote->QuoteId.". ";
        echo $quote->Direct."<br/>";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: i am using this api but have same issue but sky scanner api first time does not get full result so run api 3 times in at a time and get full result.

Comment: I hope that's not your real API key. If it is, you should invalidate it and generate a new one _immediately_.

Comment: No, that's not my real one. That's the Skyscanner API key from the documentation.

Comment: @pawan sen That only helps using the LivePricing API where updates are still pending and the results are not complete immediately. But it shouldn't apply to the browseroutes API where results are cached and should be available immediately.

Comment: @tom_lehnert your free api key does not return full detail please ask skyscanner support team and buy full features api key.

Comment: @pawansen Even if I use my personal API key, I get the same result. It shows me 3 results but it returns 9 when using some online JSON editor.

Comment: Okay, I tried to execute the same code not on my localhost Xampp machine but on some cheap webspace from Godaddy and it returned 9 results instead of just 3! So I think that my Apache settings may be the issue...?